# C# return value inside linq list based on if statement

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

**What I have**

I have a list, which would execute only when certain conditions are met

```
var list = data.Where(!t.Area.HasValue || t => t.Area == response.Area).Select(t => new Status()
{
   PK = t.PK,
   Area = t.Area,
   Description = t.Description
   //other stuff
}).ToList();
```

**What I want**

This list works fine the way it is, but now I want to modify it slightly. For one of the variables, I want to run an if-else statement, and that variable will be the return result of if-else statement execution

```
var list = data.Where(!t.Area.HasValue || t => t.Area == response.Area).Select(t => new Status()
{
   PK = t.PK,
   Area = t.Area,
   Description,    //<---------------returns the value of executed if-else statement
                                         //if (t.Area.HasValue) Description = a;
                                         //else Description = b;
   OtherStuff = t.OtherStuff
}).ToList();
```

My question is: **Where to I place that if-else condition in order to properly execute it?**

**What I tried**

I tried placing if-else statement inside the place of actual variable between two commas.

I tried using temp variable, whose result will be returned, but I don't want to have this temp variable in my list.

I tried having extra conditions inside Where() before I realized it is a set of conditions to actually execute that list.

Searching SO and internet did not get me desired outcomes to try out (hopefully, I was not just using a wrong search criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = data.Where(!t.Area.HasValue || t => t.Area == response.Area).Select(t => new Status()
{
   PK = t.PK,
   Area = t.Area,
   Description = t.Area.HasValue ? a : b
   //other stuff
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Congratulations man, you are the winner of my little RNG code! And it seems like you need to rank up as well ;)

Comment: Thanks! It was funny that we all posted the same answer simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator for it following way :

```
Area = t.Area,
Description = t.Area.HasValue ? a : b,
```

Comment: but i am the winner :D

Comment: Wow, I stepped aside for 5 minutes O_O

Comment: Since they are all the same, I will determine the winner by my little RNG code, so all of you are in the same fair conditions =)

Comment: But + 1 for all of you as a bonus =)

Comment: @VadzimSavenok RNG means?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Random Number Generator, pretty much a 3-sided dice-roll in that case.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok rule here is who posted first should be marked, but no problem :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad When I returned, I saw a tab of 3 new answers, clicked it, and they were all indeed in the same minute, but now it is impossible for me to determine who was first.

Comment: if you click on oldest tab to order by oldest, you will see mine was first :) but no worries purpose fulfilled your question is answered

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the future acceptance, but let's give some glory to the beginner and his luck, so he can be more helpful in the future =)

Comment: yeah, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = data.Where(!t.Area.HasValue || t => t.Area == response.Area).Select(t => new Status()
{
   PK = t.PK,
   Area = t.Area,
   Description = t.Area.HasValue ? a : b, 
   OtherStuff = t.OtherStuff
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you =) But RNG decided in his favor. Let him have some glory of the beginner's luck! =)